# R: how to scrape a gmail folder to a dataframe

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have set up a label/Folder "MyAlerts" for incoming google alerts in my gmail box. 
I would like to scrape them to a dataframe. My dream is to have the content of these messages in one column.

So far I have tried edeR package, but it only scrapes headers of messages.

```
dat2 <- extractMbox(username="myaccount@gmail.com",
                       password="mypass",
                       folder="MyAlerts",
                       nmail=10)
```

Can you give me a hint, where to start? Is there a better tool for google alerts? I receive them in gmail box, cannot set it to RSS (grayed out).

Comment: Probably you are missing `folder="[Gmail]/MyAlerts"`?

Comment: folder="MyAlerts" scraps headers from that folder.
folder="[Gmail]/MyAlerts" throws errors like File "C:\Users\jkotows2\PortableApps\Dropbox\R-Portable\App\R-Portable\library\rJython\jython.jar\Lib\imaplib.py", line 749, in uid
imaplib.error: command SEARCH illegal in state AUTH

Comment: do you have other folders in your Gmail? Can you try on others?

Comment: Inbox... pulls headers ok... no message body. Maybe this package is not designed to do body's of messages?

Comment: did you try the [`gmailr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmailr/index.html) package?

Comment: I am trying now. It is not clear for me how to auth... I have set up keys, got the file in json and get errors when trying to auth in browser: 
gmail_auth("gmailrproject-059c83b105a7.json", scope = "compose")

401. That’s an error.

Error: invalid_client

The OAuth client was not found.